# Maths on numpy dtypes

Tags: python, numpy

It seems that doing math using numpy dtypes (specifically uint32) takes longer than doing math on regular python ints. Here's my real-life example code:

```
import numpy

## Binary encoding of DNA as python int
bDic = {'A': 0 ,'C': 1 ,'G': 2 ,'T': 3  } # DNA to 32bit binary...
tDic = ['A',    'C',    'G',    'T'     ] # ...and back again :)
range32 = range(0,32,2)

def string_up2bit(string):
    up2bit = 3
    for char in reversed(string): up2bit = (up2bit << 2) + bDic[char]
    return up2bit
def up2bit_string(value):
    up2bits = [((value >> x) & 3) for x in range32]
    return ''.join([tDic[up2bit] for up2bit in up2bits[:-up2bits[::-1].index(3)-1]])

## Binary encoding of DNA as numpy uint32 (what i will actually be saving to disk)
n0,n1,n2,n3 = numpy.uint32(0),numpy.uint32(1),numpy.uint32(2),numpy.uint32(3)
npbDic = { 'A': n0 ,'C': n1 ,'G': n2 ,'T': n3 } # DNA to 32bit binary...
nptDic = { n0 :'A', n1 :'C', n2 :'G', n3 :'T' } # ...and back again :)
nprange32 = list(numpy.arange(0,32,2,dtype='uint32'))

def np_string_up2bit(string):
    up2bit = n3
    for char in reversed(string): up2bit = (up2bit << n2) + npbDic[char]
    return up2bit
def np_up2bit_string(value):
    up2bits = [((value >> x) & n3) for x in nprange32] # The 32 here makes it 32bit only.
    return ''.join([nptDic[up2bit] for up2bit in up2bits[:-up2bits[::-1].index(n3)-1]])

## Begin test:
## Read 10000000 lines of DNA from a file, convert into binary and back again.
DNA = 'ATTCGACTTGACTG'
r = 0
while r != 10000000:
    r += 1
    #up2bit_string(string_up2bit(DNA))        # Takes 1min 12sec
    np_up2bit_string(np_string_up2bit(DNA))   # Takes 1min 45sec
```

As you can see right at the bottom, using the numpy uint32 takes 45% longer than the python int version. There should be no conversion of NumPy uint32s to python ints in the code above to explain the slowdown, it is simply that working with uint32s seems to be slower. This translates to days of extra computation time on the real-world data sets.

Does anyone have any idea how to speed this up? Perhaps theres a way to make uint32 maths in python the default? Perhaps i should try ctypes instead of numpy dtypes?

**Edited so anyone can test the code with having DNA data to hand.**

Comment: Can you measure how much of that time is spent in system calls, how much in the python interpreter and how much in the native (i.e., C, C++, Fortran) libraries that NumPy is based on? NumPy might delegate even simple operations on its types to the native libraries, so if the iteration is done in python (instead than implicitly in NumPy, as happens with vector operations) I could imagine the many separate library calls cause the performance hit you see.

Comment: I will give it a look using cProfile :)

Comment: To optimize any NumPy-using code, try to replace as many explicit loops as possible (especially tight inner loops) with [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) operations.

Comment: numpy types are meant to be used in numpy arrays, not as stand alone numbers.    When used alone `np.uint32(1)` is a mini-array, with all of its overhead (including memory).

Comment: @hpaulj Ahhh, this must be the reason why! So I guess I should try using ctypes instead of numpy's dtypes for single-values - although then i run into another issue because ctypes cannot be hashed thus cannot be the key in a dictionary.
But right now I think das-g and you might be right - put all my data into arrays and operate on them simultaneously. Somehow :P

Comment: Yep, maybe that's caused by additional overhead of using native lib for such small operations. Numpy is fast on vectorized operations (SIMD as @das-g said above).

Comment: @J.J
But you can think about int that it's already hash, why would you use dicts where keys are ints?

Comment: Olologin - haha, very good point! I replaced tDic with "tDic = ['A','C','G','T']" and that shaves off about 20 seconds from the python int version of the code, but unfortunately for the uint32 code, if you pass a uint32 as an index, it has to first be converted to a python int, so the execution time skyrockets to 15+ minutes.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert DNA sequences to this binary representation and back again, by the way? Is this about compression/decompression for storage?

Comment: Yup, exactly - I convert to and back again simply to use both encoding and decoding algorithm. In the larger program, the encoded data is stored in a numpy uint32 structured array to save space storing it in RAM. But whilst this means I can process my data without offloading stuff to disk, it turns out numpy's recall of data from a structured array is actually pretty slow. Vectorization is very fast, but operating on individual items is slow. Im now looking at Cython because numpy & cython work very well together: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html

Comment: BAM (supposedly the format of your input file) seems to already be a compressed binary format that allows indexing for optimized random access performance. Maybe it would make sense to work directly on that, only accessing the specific parts of data you need at a given moment? (I.e., instead of using a compressed representation in RAM, keep as little information in RAM as possible to begin with.) There's probably libraries on PyPI that allow you to leverage these indexing and random access capabilities.

Comment: The BAM format is exactly as you say, binary-compressed DNA sequence information, but unfortunately it contains a lot of other data as well like where in the genome the DNA comes from, etc. But that isn't really the issue, the issue is that the above code is to be used in a larger program that stores the *counts of all sub-strings in the BAM file*.
So if i wanted to know how many 'ACCTG's there were, one option would be to walk through the whole BAM file counting them. The other would be to pre-compute and store in memory "ACCTG = 889", which is what im trying to do (with a trie)